# Is it possible in matlab to explicitly format the output numbers?

Tags: matlab, number-formatting

I know about MATLAB's *format long*, *format short*, *eng ...* and so on. But short and long will always display a predefined number of decimals, with an exponent, and for example, *format bank* will display always 2 decimals.

Is there an option to put your explicit format, in a "fortran way", like f8.3 --> 1234.678 ?

I'm looking for a way to display numbers with 4 decimal points, and the rest ahead of the decimal point, with no exponent.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know of a way to specify a global format of the type you want.  `sprintf('%15.4f', x)` or `num2str(x, '%15.4f')` do what you're looking for, if you don't mind calling them explicitly each time.

Comment: I see ... oh, well. I'll leave the question a little longer ... maybe someone will come up with some other idea ...

Comment: +1. I came here to say this. I would point out that fprintf can be used to print to the console in addition to formatting. You could make a function print( dbl ) that does fprintf(1,"%5.3f\n",dbl) and use printf instead of disp.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/format.html) which is available on their website you can use

```
format shortG
```

to set the display format for the output to n.4.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation it does allow you to [format the number.](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html)

Also, the formatting is [well documented as well.](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html)

Comment: It now occured, and I forgot to mention ... I wish to change it's format in matlab, not while printing to a file or ... I want to change the format matlab uses for displaying numbers while, for example, working in its interactive prompt.

Comment: I'm not sure you can change that, that would probably be under the options if it is available. You can print the formatted number out manually.

Answer (score 3):

There are two simple solutions:

1. using the ***sprintf*** function:

   str = sprintf('%.4f', myNumber);
2. using Java-based formatting, which is much more powerful ([more information](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)):

   str = char(java.text.DecimalFormat('#.0000').format(myNumber));

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could come up with, is:

```
format bank
```

It will give you no E, and 2 decimal places.

try to read

```
help format
```

to look for other options there (*I don't use Matlab anymore... switched to Free Software :)* )

Answer (score 0):

I just use sprintf and num2str like mtrw mentioned. `sprintf()` is meant for multiple scalar arguments of various types (it works w/ matrices, but not really in a clear way). `num2str()` is meant for use with a single matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Put on top of the  Matlab (.m) File the following statement "format shortG".

Example:

```
format shortG;

Q = [0 0.54994 0.1998 0.1998;
 0 0.54994 0.1998 0.1998;
 0 0.54994 0.1998 0.1998;
];

disp(Q);
```

More options are available : [Matlab output format](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/format.html)