# how to show certain number of decimal digits

Tags: matlab, rounding, number-formatting

In Matlab, how to control the number of decimal digits for displaying in command window?

For example,

> >> x=0.4654
>
> x =
>
> ```
> 0.4654
> ```

how to display the value of the variable x as 0.5, 0.47, 0.465 respectively in command window?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible in matlab to explicitly format the output numbers ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759982/is-it-possible-in-matlab-to-explicitly-format-the-output-numbers)

Comment: As mtwr said, your question is probably answered in the post above. Use num2str.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is built in rounding to arbitrary places, but you can achieve the rounded result by doing round(x*10^*number of places*)/10^*number of places*. This prints out with the trailing zeroes, if you want to get rid of those you have to do a specially formatted print like sprintf to the degrees so in your case you could get the results you want by doing:

```
sprintf('%.1f', round(x*10)/10)
sprintf('%.2f', round(x*100)/100)
sprintf('%.3f', round(x*1000)/1000)
```

I hope that helps!

Edit: If you want to do it for matrices, I'm not sure if there's a better way but you could just loop over the rows given x as a matrix:

```
for i=1:length(x(:,1)),
disp(sprintf('%.2f\t', round(x(i,:)*100)/100))
end
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! But I was wondering what if x is a matrix. The way in your reply will display all the rows in one single row, However I hope different row in different line, just similar to display a matrix in command window.

Comment: Hey Tim, I'm not sure how to properly do it but you can display it just by looping over the rows, I edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 2):

You have control over the command window using the `format` command. I suggest you take a look at `doc format`, which gives you specific options.

If you need more precision, you'd be better off using `disp`, and / or a rounding function such as: `z = round(x/y)*y`

Answer (score 0):

Change the format.

```
format shortG
```