# Convert an exponential matrix into number matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix, say:

`corr_a1=[6 2.150000e+003   0   1.175000e+003   3.250000e+000   4.500000e+001]`

I want to convert the said values into decimal format, i.e.

`a=[6.00 2150.00 1175.00 3.25 45.00]`

How do I do this?

Comment: Duplicates: [Is it possible in matlab to explicitly format the output numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759982/is-it-possible-in-matlab-to-explicitly-format-the-output-numbers), [how to show certain number of decimal digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211371/how-to-show-certain-number-of-decimal-digits), [How to display with n decimal places in Matlab.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149348/how-to-display-with-n-decimal-places-in-matlab)

Answer (score 4):

Check [format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/format.html).