# Sort array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, number-formatting

I have a one-column array that I would like to sort in descending order. The array has values ranging from 0 to approximately 10^14. When I sort the array with

`sorted = sort(A,'descend')`

and try to look at the ten largest values, I find that

`sorted(1:10)`

gives me

> 1.0e+14 *
>
> 5.1093
>
> 0.0000
>
> 0.0000
>
> 0.0000

etc... -- Displaying these first few, large entries tells me that there's only one non-zero element, which isn't true.
However, if I skip the first couple of entries, which are far greater than the rest of the array elements, I get

> sorted(8:10) =
>
> 2.9754
>
> 2.4182
>
> 2.0799

Why does displaying these first few large array elements cause all others to be displayed as zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first number in your list is a scale factor that multiplies the entire array that follows. Because of the difference in magnitude of the elements, you will need to play with the format settings. Try

```
    format long
```

or

```
    format long e
```

to see a better representation

Answer (score 2):

You may find `sprintf` or `num2str` more useful for printing numbers at arbitrary precision.

See [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759982/is-it-possible-in-matlab-to-explicitly-format-the-output-numbers).

Relevant Matlab docs:

1. http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/format.html
2. http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html
3. http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html

Answer (score 1):

They're displayed as zero because they are essentially zero when compared to the first element (that is, they're much much smaller than 10^14). But even if they're displayed as zero, they are NOT zero. Try typing in `sorted(3)`: the result shouldn't be zero. (Edit: you already showed this above).

It's basically an issue of precision. Typing `format long` might also make this clearer.