# Format the output so that integers are padded to two digits with zeros

Tags: matlab, matrix, number-formatting

When I make a 1x10 matrix in MATLAB, such as `a=[1:10]`, it returns:

```
a =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

i. e., it ignores zero-digit from numbers 1 to 9. I'd like to have a matrix like that:

```
a =
     01     02     03     04     05     06     07     08     09    10.
```

Comment: `2` and `02` are the same number. Do you mean you want a custom way to display your matrix?

Comment: Exactly. Can I do it in MATLAB?

Comment: A similar question: [Is it possible in matlab to explicitly format the output numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1759982/859596). By the way, the [format](http://www.mathworks.it/help/techdoc/ref/format.html) command seems not to help on your specific problem.

Comment: @Luca Gereti Yes, luca. The format command does not work. I' trying to write a string that files like that: 20120601.dat . For my surprise, the program interprets as: 201261.dat . It's like zeros were supressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display numbers in a specific format, you can overload the `disp` function for the specific type of number. In that function, you'll need to create a string with leading zeros.

If you want to create strings that contain numbers with leading zeros, you can use `sprintf`. For example, if you want to have

```
year = 2012;
month = 6;
day = 1;
```

you can create a file name with leading zeros like this:

```
fileName = sprintf('%i%02i%02i.dat',year,month,day)
fileName =
    20120601.dat
```

Comment: But now the array has a completely different type!

Comment: OK, Jonas. I wasn't specific in my statement. I'd like just as Oli wrote. The use of sprintf return strings

Comment: @MattPhillips: yes, because the leading zero has no meaning when you deal with numeric types. Anyway, I've changed my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
>> a = 1:10
a =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10

>> aa = cellstr(num2str(a(:),'%02d'))'
aa = 
    '01'    '02'    '03'    '04'    '05'    '06'    '07'    '08'    '09'    '10'
```

Note that it is now a cell array of strings:

```
>> whos a aa
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  a         1x10               80  double              
  aa        1x10              640  cell
```